# PayPal SDK going from payment review page to profilepage

Tags: java, spring, paypal

In my current Java/Spring project, I am in the phase of integration with PayPal. After configure a Java class to handle the payment process, following the instructions from [here](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Java-SDK/wiki/Making-First-Call), I run my application and try to checkout an order with paypal.

I am redirected correctly to the PayPal login page, and after the login, to this payment review page:

[image]

but then after I click on "Continue", instead of finalizing the payment, I am redirected to my profile page.

[image]

Here is my code:

```
Paypal prop = this.paypalDao.get();
String clientId = prop.getClientID();
String clientSecret = prop.getClientSecret();
APIContext apiContext = new APIContext(clientId, clientSecret, "sandbox");

if(payerId != null) {
  if(guid != null) {
    Payment payment = new Payment();
    payment.setId(map.get(guid));

    PaymentExecution paymentExecution = new PaymentExecution();
    paymentExecution.setPayerId(payerId);
    payment.execute(apiContext, paymentExecution);

    String url = request.getContextPath();
    return url+"/orders";
  }
} else {
  List<Produto> lista_de_produtos = this.getListaDeProdutos(clienteId);

  Double total = 0.0;
  for(Produto produto : lista_de_produtos)
    total = total + produto.getPreco();
  DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("0.00");
  String svalue = df.format(total).replace(',', '.');

  Details details = new Details();
  details.setSubtotal(svalue);

  Amount amount = new Amount();
  amount.setCurrency("BRL");
  amount.setTotal(svalue);
  amount.setDetails(details);

  Transaction transaction = new Transaction();
  transaction.setAmount(amount);
  transaction.setDescription(lista_de_produtos.toString());

  List<Transaction> transactions = new ArrayList<Transaction>();
  transactions.add(transaction);

  Payer payer = new Payer();
  payer.setPaymentMethod("paypal");

  Payment payment = new Payment();
  payment.setIntent("sale");
  payment.setPayer(payer);
  payment.setTransactions(transactions);

  RedirectUrls redirectUrls = new RedirectUrls();
  guid = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
  String url = request.getContextPath();
  redirectUrls.setCancelUrl( url+"/cart" );
  redirectUrls.setReturnUrl( url+"/paypal/checkout/"+clientId+"/?guid=" + guid );
  payment.setRedirectUrls(redirectUrls);

  Payment createdPayment = payment.create(apiContext);
  Iterator<Links> links = createdPayment.getLinks().iterator();
  while (links.hasNext()) {
    Links link = links.next();
    if (link.getRel().equalsIgnoreCase("approval_url")) {
      map.put("redirectURL", link.getHref());
      redirectURL = link.getHref();
    }
  }
  map.put(guid, createdPayment.getId());
  payment.setId(map.get(guid));
}

return redirectURL;
```

Can someone tell me, what am I missing here?

Comment: at least hide those personal details there like telephone, email id etc...

Comment: What is request.getContextPath() returning? If this is a relative url (without domain name), then PayPal doesn't know where to send the customer back to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try printing this value:

```
System.out.println(url+"/paypal/checkout/"+clientId+"/?guid=" + guid);
```

The result should be `https://www.yoursite.com/paypal/checkout/<number>/?guid=<number>`, or a page that would direct there (leaving out `https://` to save on bytes could be okay depending on your server configuration).

Additional tests you should try:

1. Try cancelling on your site.
2. Try cancelling the payment on paypal's site.

Iff one works but the second does not, then paypal is not redirecting properly, which probably means you're not giving it the right string. Also see comment by @Emile.

Comment: `leaving out "https://" to save on bytes`...... [wrong site?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/) LOL :P

Comment: @HyperNeutrino Some payment processing systems accept shorter URL lengths than is allowed by the official standard. E.g. 255 characters instead, because the bank uses fixed strings on their legacy backend. Those 8 bytes saved can be helpful sometimes. I didn't look it up for paypal though, so it may be unnecessary.